# Cygwin if then else statement - syntax error

Tags: bash, if-statement, cygwin

Where i mistaked? That script works perfectly on Debian, but cygwin shows syntax error (unexpected end of file)

```
if [ ! -r error ] ; then
echo "0"
else
echo "file exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a problem with end-of-line characters, specifically if you used CRLF (*carriage-return line-feed*).

Use `tr -d '\r' < yourscript > newfile` to strip these characters from your file and run `bash newfile`.

Comment: I have seen this advice for linux system, but cygwin "tr" doesnt have -e flag

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant `-d`. (wrong mnemonic *e*rase vs. *d*elete)

Answer (score 0):

On my current Cygwin setup, bash is in 
C:\cygwin\bin.
so for running a bash script command will be

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash  bashfile.sh
```

Hence, you need to find the path of bash in your cygwin and 
run the .sh file with correct path of bash

Comment: My problem is not in cygwin path. I run cygwin.exe and the i run script.sh after this output show me unexpected end of file

Answer (score -1):

I created and edited script via windows notepad - seems it was my problem. When i created new script in cygwin through vi editor all worked fine

P.S Editing through notepad++ and saving file for Unix system didnt help me

Comment: Install `dos2unix` package. `d2u` and `u2d` are very practice for conversion  between LF and CRLF text format